# How can I locate this element using Xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following code:

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="MainMenu1" display="block" transform="translate(1125, 0)">
   <g dp:id="Content" xmlns:dp="http://dreampark.se/extensions" width="375" height="624" id="MainMenuViewMainMenu_DynamicChild3Content" _shadowId="MainMenuViewMainMenu_DynamicChild3Content">
      <g transform="translate(0,0)" x="0" y="0" clip-path="url(#clipPath59)">
         <g display="block" transform=" translate(0,208)">
            <g id="RootMenuItem" width="376" height="50" display="block" buffered-rendering="static" transform="translate(0,0)">
               <g id="RootMenuItemIconHolder" transform="translate(25,2)" display="none">
                  <image id="RootMenuItemIcon" opacity="1.0" width="40" height="40" display="block"/>
               </g>
               <foreignObject width="260" height="30" x="65" y="10" transform="null">
                  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                     <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:22;color:#AAACAE" id="RootMenuItemText" original_x="null" fill="#AAACAE" font-size="22" width="298">Text 2</div>
                  </body>
               </foreignObject>
            </g>
            <g id="RootMenuItem" width="376" height="50" display="block" buffered-rendering="static" transform="translate(0,52)">
               <g id="RootMenuItemIconHolder" transform="translate(25,2)" display="block">
                  <image id="RootMenuItemIcon" opacity="1.0" width="40" height="40" display="block"/>
               </g>
               <foreignObject width="260" height="30" x="65" y="10" transform="null">
                  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                     <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:22;color:#AAACAE" id="RootMenuItemText" original_x="null" fill="#1D212D" font-size="22" width="298">Text 1</div>
                  </body>
               </foreignObject>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
   </g>
</g>
```

I want to locate the element with `id="RootMenuItemText"` but I need this element to be a child of an element who is following sibling of an element (which `id` is `"RootMenuItem"`) that has a child with `id="RootMenuItemIconHolder"` with a `"block"` value in the `"display"` attribute.

The element I need to locate is:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:22;color:#AAACAE" id="RootMenuItemText" original_x="null" fill="#1D212D" font-size="22" width="298">Text 1</div>
```

I have tried this Xpath:

```
//*[@id="RootMenuItemIconHolder"][@display='block']/following-sibling::*[last()]
```

But it is not locating the element. Does anyone know which Xpath expression will help me to locate the element? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
//*[@id="RootMenuItemIconHolder"][@display='block']/following-sibling::*[last()]/descendant::div[@id='RootMenuItemText']
```

You should also remember, that you have to set proper namespaces to make the selection work. That's because your document uses default `xmlns` xml namespaces on different levels of the document.